# Yii2 override bootstrap.css / bootstrap.min.css

Tags: css, yii2, assets

I change this in `bootstrap.css`:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: #DBEADC;
}
```

and this in `bootstrap.min.css`:

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover{background-color:#DBEADC}
```

When I'm updating Yii2, these changes of course are going to be overwritten. What is the best practice to handle this? I mean how can I persistently override this one color, so that all other things should be updated when a new version is coming?

Comment: Add your change in separate css file and include this file after the bootstrap's one.

Comment: Why you have to do the change both in bootstrap and bootstrap.min?? Are you using both of them?

Comment: I have no idea... I like consistency... :) Do I need to change only one of them?

Comment: @Bizley thank you, it seems to work, at least with `bootstrap.css`. Whether I have to do with `bootstrap.min.css` something I'm not sure.

Comment: *.min is minified version so it should be included instead of normal version (usually in production environment; never both version at the same time) but your line will override the property no matter if main is minified or not. How you write if ("minified" or not) doesn't really matter here.

Comment: @Bizley many thanks for your help! You are really kind!

Comment: @Bizley don't you want to add your answer as an answer please ?

Comment: Feel free to accept @JosepVidal answer. He put more work in it, mine was just a quick suggestion ;)

Comment: @Bizley excuse me but how can one contact you personally?

Comment: If really necessary - there are links in the profile to my Twitter and Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `.css` file (Under `/web/css` folder), it will always have preference over the boostrap ones that are loaded by default by Yii.

Example, on how to load own files, inside your main asset class, normally (`assets/AppAsset.php`) you must add the file path in the $css property:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css' // this right here
    ];
    public $js = [];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

This is the way of doing it, mutating files that will  get overriden after updates, WILL never be the right way.